# What does "калмыжка" mean in this context?

Tags: перевод

This is a sentence in Tolstoy's "Чем люди живы":

> Идет сапожник дорогой, одной рукой палочкой по мерзлым калмыжкам постукивает, ...

I couldn't find the word "калмыжка" used elsewhere other than in this sentence, and the closest word I can find is калмык/калмычка, which both seemed pretty irrelevant considering the context. English translations of this book seemed to translate this sentence as below:

> He trudged along, striking his stick on the frozen earth with one hand...

so the калмыжка seems to mean something like "earth". Could somebody please explain what this word is?

Comment: Tolstoy liked to use regionalisms a lot )

Comment: Первый раз такое слово вижу.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this](http://smolgu.ru/files/doc/D212_254_01/disser/savina.pdf) source :

> **Калмыжка**. Слово имеет разные звуковые формы в зависимости от говора:
>   `калмыжка`, `калмышка`, `колмыжка`, `колмышка`. Диалектное колмышка происходит
>   от комлыжка посредством метатезы, далее от существительного ком –
>   ‘уплотненный, принявший округлую форму кусок мягкого, рыхлого
>   вещества’. Ср. у В.И. Даля без указания места:
>   комлыга – ‘ком, колыга на пашне’. Значение к
>   форме калмыжка в СРНГ: ‘комки грязи; затвердевшие, спресованные комья
>   земли’

So, it's actually dialectal (in the monograph it's claimed to be from Tula region), obsolete and virtually unknown to modern native speaker word for lumps of dirt. It related to ["ком"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) and has nothing to with "калмык".